# FileZilla Filename Ordering

Tags: filenames, filezilla

After connecting to my server via Filezilla, the Filenames displayed under the remote site (right side) are alphabetized in reverse order. Filenames for the local server (left side) are alphabetized normally. How can I reverse the order of the remote site file names so that they are displayed in ascending order?

Comment: Have you tried clicking the table header column for the file name?

Answer (score 2):

On the left side, click on **Filename**  to sort out files using their name. You can sort files using File size, their type and ....

[image]